# backup oem installation without install

Tags: windows, clone, windows-activation

Situation: Purchased HP prodesk from amazon, do not want windows on the machine at this time.  Never started up windows 1st boot.  A handful of times the system did not properly boot from usb and windows 1st boot startup began.  Install process never started.  System always immediately shut down when usb boot did not work.

Problem: some how windows did not like being prevented from install and now a linux mount of the harddrive with windows oem installed gives this message

`user@debian:/home$ sudo mount /dev/sda4 /home/hd1/`

> The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
> Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
> Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
> unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
> or fast restarting.)

Goal: Without completing install or setup - To save necessary info (serial, activation code, ect) needed to install windows on the machine at a later date or "ideally" on a vm or usb to be used on that machine without install on harddrive.  This is a relatively new machine, maybe all needed info is in bios??

if goal can not be achieved can the critical partitions of an oem install be cloned and img.gz'd to reduce size and reinstalled on drive at later time for a standard clean install ?  just save sda1 sda2 sda3 and windows files from sda4

```
/dev/sda1       ntfs          WinRE         500Mib
/dev/sda2       fat32         System        100Mib
/dev/sda3       MS reserved partition        16Mib
/dev/sda4       ntfs          Windows     237.87Gib
```

Comment: It’s unnecessary; You can simply format the entire drive and install Linux; When you change your mind simply install Windows and it will automatically detect your license key and automatically activate

Comment: thanks.  would an install to usb plugged into the machine work as well ? usb would be used by same bios...

Comment: You simply reinstall Windows